# How to Select time in Date Time picker

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using a DateTimePicker in Winforms, but it is showing only Dates to select from, not the time, How can I make the control to display like the shown in this image, so that user can select the time too.

[image]

I tried to add

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM dd yyyy hh mm ss";
```

but then it shows time in the Control itself, it doesn't shows the clock as displayed in the image.

Comment: Please share your current code, what attempts you've made to solve your problem and what the results were.

Comment: how did you just displayed datetimepicker calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the `CustomFormat` for your `DateTimePicker`:

```
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt";
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
```

**NOTE:** the code above will allow user to modify all the elements: dates and time. I think that's what you want. If you want to show the `Clock`, it's a lot to do more. There are some simple `Clock` control already built for you.

You can search for more with the keyword `Clock control`, especially in `codeproject.com` (**there are tons of controls**), here is just 1:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10627/Yet-Another-Analog-Clock

Comment: Thanks @KingKing, I was about to add the same comment what you added on Note, I thought there might be some flag to set in the dateTimePicker class which will shows clock as well.

Comment: @Pankaj No, `datetimepicker` is not such full featured. You have to create your own or better use some already-built Clock control, whenever the time is changed, you can update the value for the Clock cotnrol.

Comment: @Thanks King King. Just out of curiosity I was wondering How Microsoft have made this control then, I find it hard to believe they have done custom drawing for half part and used a inbuilt control for half part.

Comment: @Pankaj that's called `Control Customization`, in `Winforms`, customizing control requires much work with `GDI+`, it's simple in logic but requires time to test and adjust.

Answer (score 4):

```
timePicker = new DateTimePicker();
timePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
timePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Reference:-http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229631.aspx

Comment: When I add this code, Then my control becomes a numeric updown in which I can do updown with only time, It doesn't display the whole control Like shown in the above image.

Comment: Not what is being asked for, the question explicitely asks for date AND time.